# Using express-formidable to get multipart data , but it makes simple post requests with request body run forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8080

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended : true
}))
app.use(formidableMiddleware());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The application is up and running on ${PORT}`)
})
```

**controller.js**
This contains the controller that takes base64 encoded image in formdata and that can be accessed with **filename** property (This is one controller which is working fine with formidable)

```js
const uploadProfilePic = async (req, res) => {
    let strArr = req.fields.filename.split(',')
    let buffer = new Buffer(strArr[1], 'base64')
    let filename =
        Date.now().toString() + '' + strArr[0].split('/')[1].split(';')[0]
    try {
        req.user.profile = buffer
        req.user.filename = filename
        await req.user.save()
        return res.status(200).json(
        customMessage(true, {
            message: 'Successfully uploaded',
        }),
        )
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).status(internalServerError)
    }
}
```

**controller2.js** This controller is not working properly, it does not even run when we use express-formidable and the post request route to which this controller is binded to, runs forever, but if we pass no request body then it runs perfectly or if we comment out:

```js
//app.use(express-formidable);
//In app.js
```

then it runs properly but then controller.js doesnt run.

```js
const updateUserData = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const {_id, email, name, username, bio, code, platform, languages } = req.body
      if (username === undefined || code === undefined || !platform || !languages)
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json(customMessage(false, 'Please Satisy Validations'))
  
      let user = req.user
      let user1 = await UserModel.findById(_id)
      user1.username = username;
      user1.code = code;
      user1.bio = bio;
      user1.platform = platform;
      user1.languages = languages;
  
      if (!user) return res.status(500).json(internalServerError())
      else {
        await user1.save()
        console.log
        return res
          .status(200)
          .json(customMessage(true, `user with ${email} updated`))
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return res.status(500).json(internalServerError())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a way to send requests through the multipart/form data and the application/json without breaking any thing. I actually spent 2 hours trying to figure out what happened and how to solve the problem. I discovered that the package "express-formidable" is no longer being maintained and has been closed down. Then I also found another package which of course solved the problem just about now "express-formidable-v2" which I believe is the continuation of the former package.

Check this https://github.com/Abderrahman-byte/express-formidable-v2 out, It is a fork of "express-formidable" package

Now you have access to your {req.fields} and {req.body}